# How to select consecutive values below a critical number?

Tags: r, indexing

Suppose I have few numbers and I wonder how I can find the consecutive values below a critical number. For example, in `Mydata`, for single values <10, find them; for consecutive values <10, find the sum.

```
Mydata = c(-10,11,-100,-8,-6,-5,15,10,22,-8.5,88,76.5,42,-85,9,100)
which(Mydata<10)
[1]  1  3  4  5  6 10 14 15
```

We can see that 3,4,5,6 and 14, 15 are consecutive numbers and 1, 10 are single numbers. So the final result should be

```
-10,-119,-8.5,-76
```

I wonder how to do this in R. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  It seems like a very specific set of requirements.  Do you have a particular application in mind?

Comment: No, this is not a homework problem, it is related to my research. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, in that case you can use the following trick.  Applying `diff` to the indexes will yield a value `1` wherever a pair of indexes is consecutive and non-`1` whenever a new block of consecutive values starts.  You can identify those block starts in a logical vector and run `cumsum` along it to generate a vector of block numbers.  Then, `tapply` can calculate the sums for you:

```
consecutive.below <- function(x, threshold) {
    o <- which(x < threshold)
    if (length(o)==0) return(x[o])
    blocks <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(o) != 1))
    unname(tapply(x[o], blocks, sum))
}
consecutive.below(Mydata, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- Mydata < 10
as.vector(tapply(Mydata*i1, rleid(i1)*i1, FUN = sum)[-1])
#[1]  -10.0 -119.0   -8.5  -76.0
```